# UICollectionViewCell in Circular shape

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Is it possible to create custom UICollectionViewCell in circular shape?

**Why I need this?**
I am trying to create custom color picker. I want to put some default color in each CollectionViewCell. These color are dynamic. That means I will be changing colors filled in cells.

**What I have tried**
1. I kept circle shaped png images in cells. But will have to change images if i want to change colors.
2. I kept circle shaped image transparent inside (in circle area). Then I changed Background color of cell. Failed as I will be changing Background image of collectionView.
3. I kept circle shaped image completely transparent except the boundary. Then I changed Background color of cell. Failed...
Help me..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use a circular image. You can make any square view circular by adjusting the layer's cornerRadius property to half of the edge. So, if your cell is 100x100, set its corner radius to 50.

You can do this in your collection view data source (`cellForItem...`) or in the `applyLayoutAttributes:` method of your cell subclass.

For more flexibility use a `CAShapeLayer` added to the background view of the cell and change its fill colour. This way the coloured area can be any shape you like, and you can add shadow effects and animations to it.

Comment: [Setting corner radius on a cell kills UICollectionView's performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979935/setting-corner-radius-on-a-cell-kills-uicollectionviews-performance)????

Comment: I haven't experienced that. Try rasterising, or using a cashapelayer as I also suggest. But try the simplest solution first, before discounting it. By the sound of it you're not scrolling, so performance shouldn't be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me 
if you need cell to be in circle remove thumbimageviewcell it the label which i m using and add your image view name

```
    cell.thumbimageviewcell.layer.cornerRadius = cell.thumbimageviewcell.frame.size.width/2;
    cell.thumbimageviewcell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    cell.thumbimageviewcell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    cell.thumbimageviewcell.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```