# Performance in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using a standard approach for a UICollectionView with a custom Cell. I've registered the Cell and all of that, but when the collectionview starts to fill the entire screen with items - the performance drops a lot and it becomes laggy. No problems when there are just a few items. The collection view is dynamic so that users can add items as desired. Also remove. What can be the problem? Or solution to turn it a bit around.

Thanks for assistance!

**Edit:**

viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[_projectsCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Cell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

// Configure the style of the three big buttons
prepareButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
prepareButton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
prepareButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

aboutButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
aboutButton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
aboutButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

createButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
createButton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
createButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

editButton.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
editButton.layer.borderWidth = 1;
editButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
// (note - may prefer to use the tintcolor of the control)


// Set up projectsCollectionView
_projectsCollectionView.delegate = self;
_projectsCollectionView.dataSource = self;

}
```

viewWillAppear:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
_objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myProjects"]];
[_projectsCollectionView reloadData];
}
```

my cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
ProjectCell *cell = (ProjectCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
// Get the amount of subjects
        NSMutableArray *subjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:_objects[indexPath.row
]]];

// Count the subjects
int subjectsCount = [subjects count];

// Set the text and integer value
cell.projectLabel.text = _objects[indexPath.row];
cell.projectCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",subjectsCount];

cell.layer.cornerRadius = 16;
cell.layer.borderWidth = 1;
cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
// (note - may prefer to use the tintcolor of the control)

return cell;
}
```

User adds new item code:

```
                // Ready to add the project, go ahead
                [_objects insertObject:newProject atIndex:0];
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
                [_projectsCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];

                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_objects forKey:@"myProjects"];
```

Comment: Share your code (specifically the one that creates the UICollectionViewCell)

Comment: What are you trying to load into your cell is important factor, let us know your code

Comment: Sorry, forgot:) Uploaded now

Comment: What you think? @Shai - take your time :)

Comment: NSMutableArray *subjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:_objects[indexPath.row
]]]; this is very slow.

Comment: Still a big laggy even when I remove it

Comment: When do you see the lag? when scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add

```
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

It can help. Also all this staff:

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 16;
cell.layer.borderWidth = 1;
cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
```

You should do in you custom cell class

Comment: Excellent! SOOO much smoother! THANKS! :)

Comment: One question, where in the custom class should I add the other code you mentioned? The initWithFrame did not do it and I can't create a viewDidLoad method @mvadim

Comment: There you have method -(void)awakeFromNib, just add there :self.layer.cornerRadius = 16;
self.layer.borderWidth = 1;
self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor; Also don't forget about #import "QuartzCore/CALayer.h"
in custom cell

Answer (score 0):

Read my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38324727/6564976). May be it will be helpful.

Comment: @Robert I added an explanation
 "There is a code for UIView subclass, which is provide you a view with opaque rounded borders and transparent hole in the middle. 
You should create needed view as usual and after that you can add view with hole over your view. Visualisation is [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lhKpO.jpg). "